# Custom Named Exports in Rollup Not Working

Tags: angular, rollupjs

I am using Rollup for the first time (following the example at angular.io) and I'm getting this error:

**'AuthHttp' is not exported by 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js'**

from this line in app.module.js:

**13: import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';**

The docs say you can correct this by specifying a custom named export in the rollup-config.js file like this:

```
commonjs({
  namedExports: {
    // left-hand side can be an absolute path, a path
    // relative to the current directory, or the name
    // of a module in node_modules
    'node_modules/my-lib/index.js': [ 'named' ]
  }
})
```

here is the relevant section of my rollup-config.js file:

```
  plugins: [
      nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
      commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
         namedExports: {
          'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js': [ 'AuthHttp' ]
        }
      }),
```

However this does not have any effect and the error remains. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion -- I hadn't run that command. When I do run it, it appears to run successfully ("Updated two packages...") but then when running rollup again my error stays the same as before. Sigh. When I run the command you suggested I do get this warning from npm:  WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.28 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0 but none was installed. Since I am using angular 4, I assume that message is bogus, but maybe not...

Comment: Was this the  part of angular.io that you are following on Rollup? https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#tree-shaking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and let me know how you get on:

rollup-config.js

```
commonjs({ include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**', 
                     'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js'],
 ..
         })
```

Did you do `npm i -D rollup-plugin-node-resolve` yet too?

jsnext is shown in the rollup-plugin-node-resolve documentation
[here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve#usage).

There is a cryptic comment about removing it in next release too in the [issues](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/issues/78).

The [rollup wiki docs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/jsnext:main) however seem odd with respect to **jsnext** too.
They just say it's superceeded by [pkg.module](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) which alone doesn't really clarify things for me. So maybe **remove flag or switch to false**?

There is a rollup [starter-project](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-project/blob/master/rollup.config.js) config file. It references **pkg.module** in the targets array.

There is also a  [rollup-starter-lib](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-lib/blob/master/rollup.config.js) config example too.

And here is the rollup [guide](https://rollupjs.org/)

**Update:**

Named-exports seems to be part of [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs#usage)
`npm i -D rollup-plugin-commonjs`

> Typically, you would use this plugin alongside
>   rollup-plugin-node-resolve, so that you could bundle your CommonJS
>   dependencies in node_modules.

```
`// explicitly specify unresolvable named exports
 // (see below for more details)
 namedExports: { './module.js': ['foo', 'bar' ] },  // Default: undefined`
```

Did you setup your **tsconfig-aot.json** properly too, per [here](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#serve-the-app)?

Comment: Thanks  -- adding that second include now gives me an error saying there is a duplicate export of AuthHttp, so it seems like I can have either zero or two occurrences, but not one!  Anyway this looks like a step forward. I will work more on it later tonight.

Comment: So it looks like the resolution is to Add the angular2-jwt reference in the  include section of commonjs as you suggested AND ALSO remove reference to it from the namedExports section. Unfortunately making this change to get rid of the original warning leads to two additional warnings: .
'default' is not exported by 'node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js'
'default' is not exported by 'node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js'  I tried adding these to the include section, but this did not have any effect. Any thoughts on how to resolve those errors?

Comment: There is mention of export 'default' in the angular.io rollup-config.js. Does yours follow that? It may be worth posting the whole rollup.config.js in its current guide in you question too.

Comment: nodeResolve / rollup-plugin-node-resolve was new to me. I recently came across Rollup in a video by Curran Kelleher : JavaScript Modules & Build Tools https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4ja6HeBm6s (it was from June 2015 - so things have very likely evolved a lot since). But it game me an understanding of Rollup. At 43:39 he starts discussing Rollup. Here's the code for his example http://curran.github.io/screencasts/jsModulesAndBuildTools/examples/viewer/#/17 He also stated D3 were an early Rollup adopter. So you might find Rollup configs in that library too

Comment: Thanks for those links. I've found other references to the angular issue on Stackoverflow and Github and they are all unresolved as far as I can tell, so I'm going to give up on this for now -- it seems the angular / typescript / rollup space is just not mature enough. It probably could be made to work, but I'm going to let it go for now and try again in a few months. Since you resolved my initial question, I'm accepting your answer even though my overall problem is not solved.

Comment: I would perhaps report an angular issue on github that the documentation is  inaccurate, and perhaps reference this thread in the link. I wonder if something has changed on the rollup front since they wrote the documentation. I would have been good if you had listed the complete config as well. Not sure if plunker would work with rollup - most angular examples I've seen are using SystemJS - otherwise I'd have said link it that way